# How to define mixed array in io-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts, io-ts-library

Using latest [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/), I would like to model property `result` of `NodeLsStatusResponse` to contains objects of type `NodeStatus` or `NodeStatus404` in (`t.readonlyArray`)

How to define this relationship with io-ts?

```
export const Connection = t.union([t.literal('a'), t.literal('b')])
export type Connection = t.TypeOf<typeof Connection>

export const NodeStatus = t.type({
  connection: Connection,
  nodeId: t.string,
})

export const NodeStatus404 = t.type({
  connection: Connection,  
  host: t.string,
})

export type NodeStatus = t.TypeOf<typeof NodeStatus>
export type NodeStatus404 = t.TypeOf<typeof NodeStatus404>

export const NodeLsStatusResponse = t.type({
  code: t.literal('OK'),
  result: t.readonlyArray(NodeStatus), /// <<< I would like to have a mixed array here
})
```

Comment: How about `t.readonlyArray(NodeStatus | NodeStatus404 )` ?

Comment: I have tried did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using an union for the readonly array as:

```
export const NodeLsStatusResponse = t.type({
  code: t.literal('OK'),
  result: t.readonlyArray(t.union([NodeStatus, NodeStatus404])),
})
```